# What are the limitations of ORM in general?

Tags: orm

I know that there are a lot of ORM fans out there but how do you deal with a database with more than 300 tables and some of the tables have more than 100 fields?

Most of the sample applications that i have seen only use a few fields. Is is prudent to use ORM in such large scale? I think that ORM is redundant (why creating another layer when in reality databases do not get changed easily?).

For me it makes sense for small applications that might get moved from databases to databases or applications that can be run on multiple platforms to use ORM.

Otherwise it seems useless or simply another headache.

any idea?

Comment: Might be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230956/is-orm-fit-for-complex-projects

Answer (score 1):

I have used ORM in some projects (Hibernate) and not in others. ORM limitations are the same as for all abstractions, you give up some flexibility and you must invest in learning the specifics of the implementation. However you typically gain coding efficiency, reduce duplication, centralize configuration, and get other improvements that are specific to the implementation. Note that database portability is not always without effort - obviously not if you use vendor-specific features.

You don't mention whether your project already has a data access implementation. If you're starting from scratch then the size of the database should not concern you too much as ORM should actually save you more on a bigger database in terms of efficiency and reducing duplication. However if you're contemplating replacing an existing data access implementation and you don't foresee the database changing much then your efforts will almost certainly outweigh the benefits.

BTW, I suspect sample applications use small databases because they're less effort to create and easier for users to understand the examples, not because the developers think that their ORM solution is only appropriate for small databases

Answer (score 0):

The great added value of the ORM is that the business logic developers can focus on interaction with objects rather than database tables.

I.e. sometimes your business object might be quite complex or use multiple database tables (i.e. `@SecondaryTable` in JPA 2.0). You don't need to know how the entity is represented in the database in order to do your job.

And what about relations? As a developer, I don't need to know if the relation is realised as a join table, foreign key or whatever. I just need to set appropriate object-oriented associations and the ORM will do the rest of the work for me.

I've seen quite a large projects (> 50 developers) that worked fine on the ORM even besides in that time the tools hasn't been so good and mature as now.

You might want to see this thread: [Is ORM fit for complex projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230956/is-orm-fit-for-complex-projects)